# How can I get a nuget package for `SPUtility` compatible with `Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM`?

Tags: 2013, csom, sputility

In CSOM, you could use SPUtility to get the members of a security group. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314767/getting-members-of-an-ad-domain-group-using-sharepoint-api/6164703

I use the nuget package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM" version="15.0.4711.1000" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

to do all of my CSOM work. But this is missing this utility package.

Am I missing an import? How can I get a compatible Nuget package with this SPUtility class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPUtility is not available in the CSOM, and it never has been. The links you provided relate to the server object model. To have access to it you need to be on a machine with SharePoint installed and add a reference to SharePoint.dll.

Classes in the CSOM will have `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` in their namespace.

Comment: ok got it. that makes a lot of sense why that was always complaining when I tried to use it. I realized I should be using `System.DirectoryServices` instead.